# Pass cookie information to gif on external domain

Tags: apache, cookies, google-analytics, mirror

I need to mirror the Google Analytics traffic to our sites to a log file.

The company has ~20 domains that need to be mirrored, so I would rather capture all that information in one location, rather than retrieve log files from ~20 locations.

I have the tracking gif stored at  tracking.companysite.com, running on Apache/Linux.

I have a CustomLog format set and trying to capture the cookie:

```
LogFormat "%h %v %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{Cookie}i\"" googleanalytics
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/google_log "googleanalytics"
```

Everything passes, but what the log file outputs for the cookie is:

```
"-"
```

The cookie information should be captured from a utmcc url parameter, but that parameter is not being passed to the remote tracking gif when I look at that request in the network panel.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxx']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.companysite.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_setLocalRemoteServerMode']);
    _gaq.push(['_setLocalGifPath', 'http://tracking.companysite.com/__utm.gif']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

What is the proper way to get the cookie information logged to the logfile, without a utmcc value being passed?  Is it possible to transfer cookie information to an external domain?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this.

The tracking gif has to be stored on the same domain or a subdomain of where the traffic is coming from.

As soon as I set  'setDomainName' to mysite.com,  and the 'setLocalGiftPath' to //tracking.mysite.com,  the response header to the gif returned a cookie, and it is logging correctly to the server.

So --  It was a cross domain issue, as I was expecting.